# Gráfica multilíneas en JS

Tags: javascript, json, chart.js

Estoy tratando de crear una gráfica a base de un archivo JSON, la estructura de este es la siguiente:

```
[
    {
        "id_productores": "1",
        "round(fruta.peso_kg, 2)": "12250.20",
        "id_embarque": "77"
    }{
        "id_productores": "2",
        "round(fruta.peso_kg, 2)": "5364.00",
        "id_embarque": "77"
    },
    {
        "id_productores": "3",
        "round(fruta.peso_kg, 2)": "6428.60",
        "id_embarque": "77"
    },
    {
        "id_productores": "4",
        "round(fruta.peso_kg, 2)": "1338.00",
        "id_embarque": "77"
    },
    {
        "id_productores": "5",
        "round(fruta.peso_kg, 2)": "1613.60",
        "id_embarque": "77"
    },
    {
        "id_productores": "1",
        "round(fruta.peso_kg, 2)": "1565.00",
        "id_embarque": "78"
    },
    {
        "id_productores": "2",
        "round(fruta.peso_kg, 2)": "1243.40",
        "id_embarque": "78"
    },
    {
        "id_productores": "3",
        "round(fruta.peso_kg, 2)": "739.40",
        "id_embarque": "78"
    },
    {
        "id_productores": "4",
        "round(fruta.peso_kg, 2)": "711.20",
        "id_embarque": "78"
    },
    {
        "id_productores": "5",
        "round(fruta.peso_kg, 2)": "1198.20",
        "id_embarque": "78"
    },
    {
        "id_productores": "1",
        "round(fruta.peso_kg, 2)": "191.40",
        "id_embarque": "79"
    },
    {
        "id_productores": "2",
        "round(fruta.peso_kg, 2)": "1672.20",
        "id_embarque": "79"
    },
    {
        "id_productores": "3",
        "round(fruta.peso_kg, 2)": "4063.80",
        "id_embarque": "79"
    },
    {
        "id_productores": "4",
        "round(fruta.peso_kg, 2)": "8811.40",
        "id_embarque": "79"
    },
    {
        "id_productores": "5",
        "round(fruta.peso_kg, 2)": "4245.50",
        "id_embarque": "79"
    },
]
```

Con esos datos la gráfica que quiero lograr es la siguiente (a razón de ejemplo los valores no coincidien con los de JSON):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En donde cada línea graficada representa los valores de `fruta_kg`, del JSON. Tomando en cuenta que el numero de lineas puede ir de **1 a n**.

Utilizo, actualmente `Chart.js`, pero hasta ahora solo se que se pueden pintar múltiples líneas utilizando muchos dataset o arrays por separado, mi problema es que el numero de datos varia según una consulta SQL.

Función que pinta el grafico con solo un array de datos:

```
const ctx = document.getElementById(id).getContext('2d');
  if(window.grafica){
    window.grafica.clear();
    window.grafica.destroy();
  }
  
  window.grafica = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'line',
      data: {
          labels: datosX,
          datasets: [{
              label: texto,
              lineTension:0,
              borderColor: 'rgb(51, 184, 255)',
              data: datosY,
              pointStyle: 'circle',
              pointRadius: 8,
              pointBackgroundColor: 'rgb(0,120,215)'
          }]
      },options:{
        title:{
          display:true,
          text:titulo
        }
      }

  });
```

Tengo entendido que para pintar más de una lineal debería repetir más de una vez lo siguientes (modificando la fuente de datos para cada line a pintar):

```
{
label: texto,
lineTension:0,
borderColor: 'rgb(51, 184, 255)',
data: datosY,
pointStyle: 'circle',
pointRadius: 8,
pointBackgroundColor: 'rgb(0,120,215)'
}
```

Comment: Hola! Por favor, comparte el código que le envías a Chart.js, conozco esa librería pero no entiendo tu pregunta. ¿Buscas crear un gráfico "dinámico" cierto? es decir, que la data que recibe tu gráfico ¿sea dinámica?

Comment: Lo que se busca o busco, en si, es poder pintar dinámicamente una fuente de datos, como se puede observar en el JSON existen 5 diferentes `id_productores` los cuales serian cada una de mis lineas a pintar, cada `id_productores` cuenta con 3 puntos diferentes, es asi como yo podria pintar 5 lineas, cada linea con 3 puntos en la gráfica. ¿No se si me explico?

Comment: ¿Podrías postear un ejemplo donde utilices dos datasets (para crear dos líneas)? Para poder implementarlo en mi respuesta junto con la función para los datasets apartir de tu array.